# Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey failing intermittently

Tags: .net, registry

I have some code like so  ( winforms app .NET 2.0 )
    RegistryKey regKey=Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey@"SOFTWARE\cPaperless\TTC\Settings", false);

This code is failing every once in a while on Win7 and Vista when UAC is on ( by failing i mean the key is null.) Note that the Key is definitely existing and I can see it in the registry
Furthermore another part of the product uses the same key in HKLM but that code is in C++ and that works every time
    LONG lRetVal = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\cPaperless\TTC\Settings",  0, KEY_READ, &hKeyTTC_LM);

What could be going wrong here. Has anyone seen this behaviour before
TIA

Answer (score 1):

Possible [Registry Virtualization](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/788151-registry-localmachine-opensubkey-returning-null) issue?